# How to include highcharts with bower?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bower

I would like to use highcharts. I did `bower install highcharts.com` ([highcharts](https://github.com/ewen/bower-highcharts) recommends using [highcharts.com](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com).

However, I have no idea what to include in my html file. I am guessing `bower_components/highcharts.com/js/highcharts.src.js`. But this is a huge file, and it will slow the build process if I minify it every build...

How should I include highcharts with bower ?

Comment: don't you have highchats.min.js in the package you have downloaded from highcharts.com.

Comment: in `bower_components/highcharts.com`, I have no `highcharts.js`or `highcharts.min.js`. I am wondering if this is the right bower package  for just including highcharts. Because the bower_components folder is huge and contains all examples, demo and build tools.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into the same problem you can do the following for highcharts

> bower install highcharts-release

and to get highstock you can do this

> bower install highstock-release

and you would include one of the following

```
'/bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.js'
'/bower_components/highstock-release/highstock.js'
```

Answer (score 13):

As Erik mentioned, use the release version of Highcharts JS:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts-release

If you're using grunt, simply run grunt bower-install and it will install the dependencies into your project.

Otherwise, include the javascript files that are part of the package:

```
bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.js
bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts-more.js
```

and if you plan on exporting:

```
bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/exporting.src.js
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the release version: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts-release.

> This is the official shim repo for Highcharts JS releases including
>   minified files. It is optimized for inclusion by Bower.