# How are the bower dependencies in jHipster organized?

Tags: gulp, bower, jhipster, main-bower-files

I want to integrate highstock (highstock.js in highcharts)  into my jHipster project. Hence I added the following to my bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "highcharts" : "4.2.6",
  "highcharts-ng": "0.0.12"
},
"overrides": {
  "highcharts-ng": {
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8",
        "highcharts": "4.2.6"
    }
  }
}
```

When I build my project with this configuration gulp imports the javascript dependencies in index.html file like this:

```
<script src="bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

But what I actualy need is only highstock.js:
[Highcharts project overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ezgm.jpg)

How can I control, what gets imported here?

Comment: Maybe you can get an answer with this post: [how-to-include-highcharts-with-bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042458/how-to-include-highcharts-with-bower)

Comment: No, it actually doesn't answer the question, as my question is specific to jHipster. I want to know how the gulp build in jHipster decides which *.js file it includes. In my case I would have wanted to include highstock.js instead of the imported highcharts.js, highcharts-more.js and exporing.js, which are all in the same folder (as shown in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in the used gulp plugin "main-bower-files" which is used by jHipster and documented [here](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#main).

The gulp build script decides based on the highcharts/bower.json file what it imports. In the case of highcharts the following is specified:

```
{
  "name": "highcharts",
  "version": "v4.2.6",
  "main": [
    "highcharts.js",
    "highcharts-more.js",
    "modules/exporting.js"
  ]
}
```

If you want to overriede this you can do so in your project bower.json in the "overrieds" section and specify which javascript it should import:

```
"dependencies": {
  "highcharts" : "4.2.6",
  "highcharts-ng": "0.0.12"
},
"overrides": {
  "highcharts": {
    "main": "highstock.js"
  },
  "highcharts-ng": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "1.5.8",
      "highcharts": "4.2.6"
    }
  }
}
```